# Different .htaccess rewrite rules for new directory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

My .htaccess currently has the following behaviour using the rewrite rules below:

`https://example.com/abcd?lol=true`

- if file `/abcd.php` exists, open `https://example.com/abcd.php?lol=true`
- if directory and file `/abcd/index.php` exist, open `https://example.com/abcd/index.php?lol=true`
- else open `https://example.com/index.php?lol=true`

-> in all three cases the address bar must still show `https://example.com/abcd?lol=true`

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [END]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [END]
```

Now to my question: I have a new directory `/blog/`, where the following must happen:

`https://example.com/blog/abcd?lol=true`

- open `https://example.com/blog/index.php?lol=true`

-> **the address bar must still show `https://example.com/blog/abcd?lol=true`** so I can use php to read the `abcd` part, which could be an article name.

How can I append my .htaccess code to achieve this?

Comment: "if directory and file `/abcd/index.php` exist" - The `.htaccess` file you posted does not currently do this (#2) (but you state that it does)? Do you have any other directives? Any other `.htaccess` files?

Comment: I have edited the post to include my entire `.htaccess` - maybe there was a part I thought to be irrelevant that wasn't? My structure is: I have only one `.htaccess` - in my root directory - there is none in `/abcd/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Aside:* You're not actually doing anything for `#2` (ie. "if directory and file `/abcd/index.php` exist...") - you are probably relying on default behaviour by mod_dir. However, if you request `/abcd?lol=true` and `/abcd` exists as a physical directory, there will be a 301 external redirect to append the trailing slash (ie.  `/abcd/?lol=true` ) which will then result in `/abcd/index.php` being served. So, this does not strictly show `/abcd?lol=true` in the address bar as you suggest. Is that what you are seeing?

---

To implement the `/blog/abcd?lol=true` to `/blog/index.php?lol=true` rewrite then replace your last rule with the following:

```
# Prevent further processing if a file or directory is requested directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [END]

# Route requests to blog/index.php
RewriteRule ^blog/. blog/index.php [END]

# Everthing else is routed to "/index.php"
RewriteRule . index.php [END]
```

This separates out the filesystem checks into their own rule so you aren't doing this twice.

---

Your previous "last" rule:

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ / [END]
> ```

You were only rewriting to `/` and then relying on mod_dir issuing an internal subrequest for `index.php` (the `DirectoryIndex`). You should instead rewrite directly to `index.php` as required (no need for the slash prefix). The capturing pattern `^(.*)$` is unnecessary here.

Comment: This works! Thanks so much. Regarding your aside: indeed for `https://example.com/test?lol=true` the address bar changes to `https://example.com/test/?lol=true` and btw, `https://example.com/blog` briefly flashes `https://example.com/blog/` before going back to `https://example.com/blog`. Any way to prevent that? (Are these "SEO-damaging redirects?")